# How to return data from separate sheet based upon conditions of a single column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that returns data of all columns based upon criteria in one cell.

[image]

where the qualifying criteria is labeled as "Yes", and would then return data for the entire row, and would not return any data if the cell does not contain "Yes".

I am struggling a bit with where I am going wrong and would appreciate any help!

Screenshots

[image: formula].

[image: reference table]

Currently used Match Index function (not pictured) where it will just return "yes" for all cell values.

Comment: Use `FILTER` as already commented on your previous question.

Comment: **[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78062409/8162520)** deleted by author 13mins back @BigBen Sir.

Comment: Formula in `B12`: `=FILTER(A3:E6,C3:C6="Yes")` to get data from different sheet: `=FILTER('your sheet name'!A3:E6,'your sheet name'!C3:C6="Yes")`

Comment: Solutions were given to your last post. say what are you upto actually?

Comment: Trying to aggregate a large data set into a view for just my team, the key word is tripping me up as "Yes", when unfortunately I change it to the real key word "Supply", it is telling me "There are no matches in the filter evaluation".

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate your formula, also are you sure abt the presence of the word `Supply` in the existing search column of your data?

Comment: Adding screenshots above in the edit @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: I said what you see when you evaluate your formula. what does it show.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya "Error No matches are found in FILTER evaluation"

Comment: See those cells have any unwanted white spaces or non breaking characters or not. I cant see your data. so i cant say what is going on your end. you should do some research.

Comment: Are you using `Google Sheets`? that specific error message relates to `GS`. A quick search on google lands on this page: **[Search](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/181277500/n-b-no-matches-found-in-the-evaluation-of-filter?hl=en)**